# BCAA use in Fasting

Tags: protein, intermittent-fasting, timing, bcaa

I see mixed opinions about BCAA drinks while fasting such as the following variety:

1. BCAA drinks in low amounts do not affect a fast.
2. Don't use BCAA during fasting
3. Only use BCAA's around a workout when fasted.

Those who recommend #1 or #3 are suggesting BCAA's don't necessarily break a fast, but is that really true?

Comment: This depends entirely on what you want to get out of your fast. Why would we recommend step 2 or 3 without knowing why you're fasting in the first place. This question is very broad, and opinion-based.

Comment: Changed my question - by "what I want to get out of a fast", I basically am asking because I want to stay in a fasted state, and BCAA's kick you out of that state, I want to avoid that.  But that is where there are contrary opinions.

Comment: The science (as you note) is sort of mixed, but the common theme that I am seeing is that if it provokes an insulin response you have broken the fast.

Comment: Yeah and ultimately I've seen: keep it to 10 grams and your fine...  But others say your body will invoke an insulin response for any BCAA.  I just read tonight Jim Stoppani says it's fine to take a little BCAA during a fasted workout.  It's all so confusing !

Answer (score 1):

2 - BCAA will definitely brake your fast, as it actually has calories and Leucine (the main bcaa aminoacid) is highly insulinogenic so you will have insuline response to that.